# Will the Access App in SharePoint 2013 work in a Office 2010 environment

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I have SharePoint 2013 
MS Office 2010
MS Access 2010 locally

I want to use the Access App which is one of the apps within SharePoint 2013, but I get an error.  Central Admin says no luck as we are still in a MS Office 2010 environment.  Is this true ?

I thought the whole purpose of a SharePoint 2013 Apps is I do not need Office 2013 locally ?  The SharePoint 2013 package I thought would provide the functionality of the Access app regardless of my Office environment

Answer (score 1):

Access 2010 is not supported with access app.

> If you have an Access 2010 web database, you can edit it in Access
>   2013 or later, but you can’t update it to an Access app.

If you wan to use the access app then you need the office 2013 or I think you configure the access service 2010 that may solve your purpose.